# Why is /textbackslash{} inserted in .tex from knitr Rmd figures?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I have a results section that includes code chunks and text. When I knit my Rmd to a pdf, two of my figures have LaTeX code surrounding them. The captions are not properly rendered. Looking at my Results.tex file, I can see that I have several `\textbackslash{}` inserted in the figure LaTeX code. I'm assuming this is what is causing the figure captions to not work properly as the working figures do not have these mystery `\textbackslash{}`. I can not figure out why only 2 out of my 8 figures have this issue, or how to stop `\textbackslash{}` from being inserted into the code.

Here is the YAML and example of a problem code chunk that contains the broken graph:

````
---
bibliography: library.bib
csl: journal-format.csl
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \doublespacing
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{gensymb}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: yes
indent: true
---

# Results

```{r graph, echo=FALSE, fig.keep = 'all', dev = 'pdf', fig.show = "hold", fig.align= 'center', out.width="70%", fig.asp=0.618, fig.width=6, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE,  fig.cap= "The relationship (caption has parenthesis) and % symbols. \\label{graph}"}

## This is the Rmd chunk that has \textbackslash{} inserted into the .tex file and will not 
# display figure captions correctly in the final .pdf
````

Part of my .tex file that shows \textbackslash{}

```
\textbackslash{}begin\{figure\}

\{\centering \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Thesis_Results_files/figure-latex/graph-1}

\}

\textbackslash{}caption\{The relationship (caption has parenthesis) and % symbols.
\label{Corr_to_signal_95CI_graph}\}\label{fig:graph}
\textbackslash{}end\{figure\}
```

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1034 see here. When there are special characters in figure captions, you have to either use bookdown or escape the characters, e.g. \\%.

Comment: @J_F  That did it. Thank you, way too simple. I won't make that mistake again.